# "Unfortunately App Has Stopped" in SQLite App Android

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I'm trying to learn basic SQLite in Android.
I have created a "Contacts Manager" app in Android Studio 3.0.
But when I run it, and whenever I tap a button to insert the data into the SQLite database, it shows a "Unfortunately Contacts Manager has stopped" error.

Here is the code for DatabaseHelper.java:

```
package com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME+ "( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, MOBILE_NUMBER INTEGER, EMAIL TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String name, int mobile_number, String email){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("NAME", name);
    contentValues.put("MOBILE_NUMBER", mobile_number);
    contentValues.put("EMAIL", email);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1) 
        return false;

    else 
        return true;

}
}
```

And the code for MainActivity.java:

```
package com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
Button insert;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNewContact.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

And the code for AddNewContact.java:

```
package com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddNewContact extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText name, mobile_number, email;
Button save;

private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_contact);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean result = databaseHelper.insertData(name.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(mobile_number.getText().toString()), email.getText().toString());
            if(result)
                Toast.makeText(AddNewContact.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            else
                Toast.makeText(AddNewContact.this, "Data Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

And the LogCat output is:

```
02-15 23:54:10.179 3073-3086/com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae3e4420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae3d28b0)
02-15 23:54:10.194 3073-3086/com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae3e4420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae3d28b0)
02-15 23:54:10.640 3073-3073/com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-15 23:54:10.660 3073-3086/com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae3e4420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae3d28b0)
02-15 23:54:11.151 3073-3086/com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae3e4420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae3d28b0)
02-15 23:54:11.375 3073-3073/com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-15 23:54:11.512 3073-3086/com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae3e4420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae3d28b0)
02-15 23:54:11.648 3073-3086/com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaab0a780
02-15 23:54:25.934 3073-3073/com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-15 23:54:25.935 3073-3073/com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager, PID: 3073
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.abdulbasitmehtab.contactsmanager.AddNewContact$1.onClick(AddNewContact.java:28)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post the logs here??

Comment: Can you analyze the code and tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: post your logs....also i suggest you learn Room Persistence Library The Room persistence library provides an abstraction layer over SQLite to allow fluent database access while harnessing the full power of SQLite https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Comment: From what I can see, your EditTexts variables are not instantiated, so when you try to getText() from one of them the app will throw an exception.

Comment: There could be multiple places that may make it crash. That is why your logs from the error are so important as @Tigo2018 has asked for.

Comment: I've added the LogCat output to the question. @Tigo2018

Comment: as @Carlos explained you forgot the initialization of the edittext

Comment: you haven't initialized your edittext name. Initialize it just as you initialized the button.

Comment: I've pointed out that just now in the code.
Thank you.